# Requesting Camera permission with Android SDK 23

Tags: java, android, permissions, android-camera, android-permissions

I'm trying to ask the user to accept a camera permission request. I placed this in my `onCreate()` method.  It's saying it cannot resolve the symbol 'CAMERA'. What's wrong?

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1);
            }
        }
```

Comment: `import android.hardware.Camera;`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work! Doesn't suggest an import and manually importing it doesn't do anything either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to import the correct `Manifest`. You probably have something like this:

```
import <your_package_name>.Manifest;
```

Remove it and change with:

```
import android.Manifest;
```

Comment: That worked. In fact I didn't even import the Manifest initially because I didn't require it in this activity prior to updating my SDK. Thanks.